# User disconnects often

Tags: node.js, apache, express

First, I literally learned nodejs today.

I have a nodejs application that uses express. I have proxied it through apache. The application works fine (the server streams data in real time to the user presented on a browser), but for some reason, after some random amount of time, the user disconnects. My `server.js` looks like this

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path'),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(http),
    feed = require('./feed');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './www')));

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('User connected. Socket id %s', socket.id);

        socket.on('join', function (rooms) {
            console.log('Socket %s subscribed to %s', socket.id, rooms);
            if (Array.isArray(rooms)) {
                rooms.forEach(function(room) {
                    socket.join(room);
                });
            } else {
                socket.join(rooms);
        }
    });

    io.on('configure', function() {
        io.set('close timeout', 60*60*24); // 24h time out
    });

    socket.on('leave', function (rooms) {
        console.log('Socket %s unsubscribed from %s', socket.id, rooms);
        if (Array.isArray(rooms)) {
            rooms.forEach(function(room) {
                socket.leave(room);
            });
        } else {
            socket.leave(rooms);
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('User disconnected. %s. Socket id %s', socket.id);
    });

    socket.on('close', function() {
         console.log('Close. Socket id %s', socket.id);
    });

    socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('end. Socket id %s', socket.id);
    });
});

feed.start(function(room, type, message) {
    io.to(room).emit(type, message);
});

http.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('listening on: 8080');
});
```

After searching the web, I thought maybe there is some kind of timeout/heartbeat that is not working, so I tried

```
io.on('configure', function() {
            io.set('close timeout', 60*60*24); // 24h time out
        });
```

But it doesn't work. I am not sure how to debug these applications. Is there anything that I should try? It seems hard to believe that it is a browser issue, but I am not sure. Perhaps also something extra has to be configured in the apache proxy.

If I refresh the browser, I can see the server print that the user has connected and it starts to display data again on the browser (although sometimes for some reason it takes a couple of refresh), and then randomly stops working some time thereafter.

Comment: Have you tried taking Apache out of the picture to rule that out? It could be that Apache has some sort of request/connection timeout (either explicitly for proxied connections or not).

Comment: good point. I was thinking the same thing. Let me try that.

Comment: It is smelling like apache. When I go to the local machine and aim a browser at localhost:8080 (I believe bypassing reverse proxy), it doesn't time out. This thread explains why not use apache in front of nodejs :https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2037328